# wordpress custom plugin get all post titles and permalinks

Tags: wordpress

I'm playing around with a custom wordpress plugin. The goal is to show all posts, and when you click on one it'll make a qr code from the selected permalink.....

Problem is I have no idea how to get all the posts from within a plugin. I've been hanging out with my best friend google for a while, but our search has turned up nothing.

Question: How does one get ALL posts titles and permalinks from within a plugin?
I've been trying to use the regular 'new WP_Query' object but it returns nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [**`get_posts`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts) to display a dropdown with all posts in a plugin settings page:

```
public function posts_html()
{
    $value = get_option( 'especial_edit_post' );
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => -1 );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    echo "<select name='especial_edit_post' id='especial_edit_post'>";
    $selected = selected( '', $value, false );
    echo "<option value='' {$selected}>-none-</option>";

    foreach( $posts as $post )
    {
        $selected = selected( $post->ID, $value, false );
        echo "<option value='{$post->ID}' {$selected}>{$post->post_title}</option>";
    }
    echo '</select>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

I just ajaxed in from another file that loads the wp-load.php file.

I'll post my code up for reference in a bit.